# WordPress Plugin „Subscribe To Comments Reloaded“: Loading Scripts Only When it is Necessary

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I use the wordpress plugin Subscribe To Comments Reloaded that allows you to subscripte to comments. So this plugin is only needed on the single.php, not on home or somewhere else. But the plugin loads 2 css files and 1 JS file everywhere in the header.

there are the css files and the js..

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stcr-plugin-style-css'  href='/wp-content/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/includes/css/stcr-plugin-style.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='stcr-font-awesome-css'  href='/wp-content/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/includes/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/includes/js/stcr-plugin.js?ver=4.8'></script>
```

how can I „deregister“ these scripts and load it only on single.php?

Answer (score 0):

Use is_single() to check if you are going to display single post. Then load css and js only if is_single() returns true.

You can deregister previously added css with wp_register_style() and js with wp_deregister_script()